# Old ActionMailer templates being cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, caching, actionmailer

We're running a Rails 3.0.7 app with Passenger standalone + nginx and with ruby 1.9.2-p290, and we're seeing the strangest thing happen: After deploying some updates to a mailer template, new mails coming from the app *sometimes* have the updates applied, and sometimes the old template is being used.

I can't find anything about cached ActiomMailer templates online, and running `rake tmp:cache:clear` does not address the issue either, fwiw.

Has anyone ever experienced such a thing?  Is there a definitive solution for this problem?

thanks,

Jacob

Comment: Did you restart the app? Are you using DelayedJob?

Comment: Does the problem occur in all environments?

Comment: I had the same problem but forgot to restart DelayedJob. They seem to cache the mailer templates.

Comment: 1. Restart Nginx
2. Restart DelayedJob / any workers you are using for email delivery
3. Make sure you have the right code on all the servers if the servers are load-balanced

Comment: I'm having this same problem, also with Rails 3 and Resque.

Comment: The same situation, when you using sidekiq :) Restarting solved all problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar situations in our application, and we use Resque.

If I'm changing anything regarding mailers (which the Resque workers handle), I need to restart the workers.

Kill the workers and respawn them, it sounds like some of them might have the old environment loaded and others do not.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well, although I wasn't using Resque to send mail. After staring at the offending templates for a while, I realized some of my inline CSS was incorrectly formatted (improper font-family and padding declarations) and that the template may have been ignoring everything else next to those declarations. As a result, it looked like it was pulling the old templates rather than rendering the new rules. Not sure if this is documented anywhere..

So, basically, I was lazy and it cost me a few hours of the day.